# Using Python to Map Keys and Data Type In kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which takes only `kwargs`. The argument `kwargs['content']` contains a `user` and `theme` keys:

```
> content = "{'user': 1, 'theme':'red'}"
> kwargs['content'] = content
> m = Message(**kwargs)
```

I need a flexible way to model what is in `kwargs['content']` and check...

- some keys in kwargs['content'] are always present.
- always make sure the values are not null and match the type.

This is what I have tried, but I feel like there is a better way.

```
class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        for field in self._hash_model():
            if field not in kwargs['content']:
                raise ValidationError('Missing % field'.format(field))
            # check type
            # turn to json



    def _hash_model(self):
        """
        My model of values that need to be in content
        """
        model = {
             'user': int,
             'theme': str
         }

        return model
```

I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: `__init__` method is also taking `*args`??

Comment: `content` is a `str` or a `dict`?

Comment: @CPanda content is passed in as a string unfortunately!

Comment: @Spaceships why _unfortunately_?

Comment: then `if field not in kwargs['content']:` will check membership in `str`, which I thinkis not what you want.

Comment: @AKS unfortunate because a dict would be easy to work with.

Comment: @Spaceships don't we all want the easy things :). Or have you chosen this as an exercise and hence the complexity? If you do pass content as string you can use `json.loads` to get the dict.

Comment: @ CPanda Thats just an example of what I'm trying to do. I need a way to create a buleprint of what should/needs to be inside the ``content`` kwarg. That way if someone adds in something they should not or a value is missing it will error.

Comment: @AKS :)  the value of ``kwargs['content']`` is given as string becuase it will be given to me over http which is also a string. I need to somehow map what is in side it, if something is missing raise an error.

Comment: @AKS so ``json.loads`` turns it into a ``dict``! Ok, I guess that way I could check each value and type from that, nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following works for you. Change the `__init__` to

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    content = json.loads(kwargs["content"]) # assuming kwargs has "content" key
    for key,val in self._hash_model().items():
        field = content.get(key) # returns None if absent
        if field and typeof(field) is val:
            # go ahead
        else:
            raise SomeException
```

Factor out the validation logic to a method if you see fit. Comment if it does not work.

Comment: Ok this gets me on the right track, partial  credit to @AKS for json.loads